# Main thread not responding when using backgroundworker in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, backgroundworker, readfile

i have a program that uses several `background workers` that continuously `load and read text files (size can up to 1MB)` and update to oracle database.

The problem i am having is whenever the background worker is reading files, the `main thread` will become `not responding` which it should not be. Is this the default behaviour when reading files, is there any way to solve it?

Thanks, any help will be very much appreciated.

**Update: [brief view of my program code]**

```
    private void program_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bw1.RunWorkerAsync();
        bw2.RunWorkerAsync(); //same function as bw1 but different directory
    }

    private void bw1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            bw1.ReportProgress(0);
        }
    }

    private void bw1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        directoryInfo = /* directory url */;
        files = directoryInfo .GetFiles();

        foreach (FileInfo file in files)
        {
            /* 
               read file line by line 
               load data into database  
               update file loading status to UI
            */
        }
    }
```

Comment: What's your main thread? Do you mean the UI thread which displaying on screen?

Comment: Show us a complete, but concise example in code demonstrating the problem.

Comment: @ToanVo Yup, main thread refer to my user interface

Comment: Code reference please.. you can refer this.. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/system.windows.forms.application.doevents.aspx

Comment: If there is UI thread your code has problem with display somewhere else. Basically, the background thread should not factor make UI does not responsive.

Comment: @ToanVo But it does make the UI not responsive when processing files, and its very painful.

Comment: First of all never run an infinite loop without sleeping the thread. It will use up an endless river of resources.

Why are you using a background worker for this task anyway? Can't you just create a new thread? You aren't doing any work on the UI thread anyways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All your actual 'work' is being performed in the `bw1_ProgressChanged` event handler. This code is executing on the UI/Main thread.

The purpose of the `BackgroundWorker.ProgressChanged` is to allow the UI to update a progress bar or other widget. The actual work (in this case, loading files) should be performed in the `bw1_DoWork` method.

Comment: +1, I'll add that it is useful to use the Threads window in visual studio when you are at a breakpoint to see whether or not you are on the main thread.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, problem is solved. Really appreciate that~